# delay binding image to XAML

Tags: c#

in my XAML code, I bind image thru local url; 
And in my C# code, I'm downloading the images from web to local url. 
So I hope the binding action can start after the image has been donwloaded to local disk, otherwise the image can not be displayed even when the image has been downloaded. 
Is there any way to delay the binding?

Comment: Add property 'Url' which supports INotifyPropertyChanged to your view model or code behind. Update your xaml to bind to this property. Then add logic which sets this property to your local url when downloading is completed.

Answer (score 0):

pleas have a look at this links as they do exactly delay binding

http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-delaybinding

Also have a look at UpdateSourceTrigger property it might be interesting in your situation.